# Node.js never Garbage Collects Buffers once they fall out of scope

Tags: node.js, heroku, garbage-collection, buffer

I have researched a lot before posting this. This is a collection of all the things I have discovered about garbage collecting and at the end I'm asking for a better solution than the one I found.

**Summary**

I am hosting a Node.js app on Heroku, and when a particular endpoint of my server is hit, which uses a lot of buffers for image manipulation (using sharp, but this is a buffer issue, not a sharp one), it takes a very few requests for the buffers to occupy all the external and rss memory (used process.memoryUsage() for diagnostics) because even tho such variables have felt out of scope, or set to null, the OS never garbage collects them. The outcome is that external and rss memory grow exponentially and after a few requests my 512 dyno quota will be reached and my dyno will crash.

Now, I have made a minimal reproducible example, which shows that simply declaring a new buffer within a function, and calling that function 10 times, results in the buffers to never be garbage collected even when the functions have finished executing.

I'm writing to find a better way to make sure Node garbage collects the unreferenced buffers and to understand why it doesn't do so by default. The only solution I have found now is to call global.gc().

**NOTE**

In the minimal reproducible example I simply use a buffer, no external libraries, and it is enough to recreate the issue i am having with sharp because it's just an issue that node.js buffers have.

Also note, what increases is the external memory and rss. The arraybuffer memory, or heapused, or heaptotal are not affected. I have not found a way yet to trigger garbage collector for when a certain threshold of external memory is used.

Finally, my heroku server has been running, with no incoming requests, for up to 8 hours now, and the garbage collector hasn't yet cleared out the external memory and the RSS. so it is not a matter of waiting. same holds true for the minimal reproducible example, even with timers, the garbage collector doesn't do its job.

**Minimal reproducible example - garbage collection is not triggered**

This is the snippet of code that logs out the memory used after each function call, where the external memory and RSS memory keep building up without being freed:

```
async function getPrintFile() {
    let buffer = Buffer.alloc(1000000);

    return
}

async function test() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        console.log(process.memoryUsage())
        await getPrintFile()
        
    }
}

test()
console.log(process.memoryUsage())
```

Below I will share the endless list of things that I have tried in order to make sure those buffers get garbage collected, but without succeeding. First I'll share the only working solution that is not optimal.

**Minimal reproducible example - garbage collection is triggered through code**

To make this work, I have to call global.gb() in two parts of the code. For some weird reason, that I hope someone could explain to me, if I call global.gb() only at the end of the function that creates the buffer, or only just after calling that function, it won't garbage collect. However if I call global.gb() from both places, it will.

This is the only solution that has worked for me so far, but obviously it is not ideal as global.gb() is blocking.

```
async function getPrintFile() {

    let buffer = Buffer.alloc(1000000);
    global.gc()
    return

}

async function test() {

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(process.memoryUsage())
        await getPrintFile()
        global.gc()
    }
    
}

test()
console.log(process.memoryUsage())
```

**What I have tried**

1. I tried setting the buffers to null, logically if they are not referenced anymore, they should be garbage collected, but the garbage collector is very lazy apparently.
2. tried "delete buffer", or finding a way to resize or reallocate buffer memory, but it doesn't exist apparently in Node.js
3. tried buffer.fill(0), but that simply fills all the spaces with zeros, it doesn't resize it
4. installing a memory allocator like jemalloc on my heroku server, following this guide: [Jemalloc Heroku Buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/gaffneyc/heroku-buildpack-jemalloc) but it was pointless
5. running my script with: node --max-old-space-size=4 index.js however again, pointless, it didn't work even with the space size set at 4 MB.
6. I thought maybe it was because the functions were asynchronous, or I was using a loop, nope, I wrote 5 different version of that snippet, each and everyone of them had the same issue of the external memory growing like crazy.

**Questions**

1. By any remote chance, is there something super easy I'm missing, like a keyword, a function to use, that would easily sort this out? Or does anyone have anything that has worked for them so far? A library, a snippet, anything?
2. Why the hell do I have to call global.gb() TWO TIMES from within and outside the function for the garbace collector to work, and why is once not enough??
3. Why is it that the garbage collector for Buffers in Node.js is such dog s**t?
   How is this not an issue? Literally, every single buffer ever declared on a running application NEVER gets garbage collected, and there is no way to find out if you are using buffers on your laptop because of the big memory, but as soon as you upload a snippet online, then by the time you realise it's probably too late. What's up with that?

I hope someone can give me a hand, as running process.gb() twice for each n type of request is not very efficient, and I'm not sure what repercussions it might have on my code.

Comment: What am I missing? Why is C++ tagged?

Comment: @sweenish sorry, stack overflow kept suggesting to use it as a tag even if I wasn't mentioning it, then i thought node.js is built on C++ and in C++ there is a way to delete/reallocate buffers whereas in Node.js there isn't so maybe someone from the C++ realm might have known what's up

Comment: @jfriend00 I let my server run for 8 hours, with no activity, after the creation of those buffers, the memory is still filled and they are not being collected, why is that?
Is there a better way to make sure they get collected on a limited memory space like 512mb? Where --max-old-space-size doesn't work? May you tell me what you mean with heap statistics? memoryUsage() displays the totalheaps etc space but it never increases, only external and RSS increase

Comment: If you are relying on libraries outside that of node.js that may use other languages it's up to those setups to clear memory. With alloc, you are allocating and that will not clear it's to preserve spacing in memory so crashes don't occur. Use another method if you need it cleared faster. I don't see any destruction of the buffer when used so really comes down to coding and not easy to detail/help with.

Comment: I'm not sure you read my question, but in the minimal reproducible example I do not use any library at all, it is the smallest example you could get and it is just a simple buffer and a function.

Comment: @MatteoBarberis did you maybe find a solution for this other than manually calling `global.gc()` ? running into the same issue